# unit testing ajax in .net

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, unit-testing

How you test ajax? What do you use?
Share information.
For me, testing ayah was torture.
I'm using jsUnit and mockajax but, nothing works...
help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but I just wrote a framework for doing JavaScript unit testing (and coverage) in .net.  So just write your ajax unit tests in what ever JS framework u want (like qUnit, JSUnit, closure, etc) and use my project to provide bindings to .Net.  Allows you to use Visual Studio and your standard CI tools to run your tests.

https://github.com/gatapia/js.net

Let me know what u think.

Thanks

Guido